# Recursive item status performance

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, performance

I have been pondering over this question for a few days now, and I can't seem to figure out what the best practice would be, so hopefully one of you guys / girls will be able to lead me down the right path.

## Data

Lets say for the sake of argument we have a Meta data table, an Item data table and an Expiration date table.

- Meta
- Items
- Expirations

A meta is what defines a collection of items and holds the general information for that collection, and there a certain criterias set on the meta which are used throughout the items layout.

An item is a derivation of a meta and holds unique data specific to that ONE item, and usually calls for the meta information. *(Note: An item can ALSO be a collection of OTHER items)*

A expiration is self explanatory, and is the expiration date of one individual item.

## Current implementation

If you enter the meta page for any given meta, it will load the items in a paginated ajax call and for each loaded item it will load a status icon. This status icon is generated EACH time it is shown, and it is recursive *(This means that if I were to put a status icon on the meta, then it would load all items for that meta and check all it's expiration dates and so fourth.)*

With the extended implementation it currently does 600 calls *(5.56 seconds)* to the database (Which is quite a load, but is neccessary based on the database layout.)

## My theory

I reckon it would show much better results for the end-user to simply store the status value in the database alongside each element, however I don't know if that is the right way to do things - considering that I would have to recursively adjust this status icon every time an element within the spectrum changes *(including having a server job setup to go and update the status based on the expiration date)*

## The question

What would the best practice for a status icon be that is recursive and has many factors and relations to keep track of?

Comment: Why are expirations separate from items

Comment: @Strawberry Because one item, can have several expiration dates (One for packaging, one for the actual item, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to cache a status icon and read it for end-user from cache only. All your load heavy stuff (recursive DB calls magic) will go into a job. Lastly you create observers for all your models that will queue this job to update cache value for changed items.

This way you will separate load heavy stuff to be handled by workers on your server side and on your client side everything will be fast and smooth. Once status icon update will be handled your end-user will see a change.